# How do I conditionally filter the first item in a python list?

Tags: python, list

I have the following function:

```
def filterArgs( args ):
    filterflag = len(args)>=1 and args[0] == "-i"
    if flag:
        args = " ".join(args[1:]).strip()
    else:
        args = " ".join(args).strip()
```

In my code I call it like this:

```
filterArgs( [ 106645929 ] )       #example 1
filterArgs( [ "-i", 106645929 ] ) #example 2
```

Is there a way to use something like a conditional operator in C and ignore the func `filterArgs`?

```
args = filterflag ? args[1:] : args
```

My objective is to write less lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in python, C's `cond ? iftrue : iffalse` translates to `iftrue if cond else iffalse`

thus, `args = args[1:] if filterflag else args`